# Why does GROUP BY with LEFT JOIN change the result of this MySQL query?

Tags: mysql

To preserve the privacy of my client information I rewrote the table and field names to generic ones, and reduced the problem to the minimum expression. This means the `GROUP BY` here maybe does not have sense, but it does in the bigger scope (as the original query has more selected values).

Data:

```
== table1 ==
 id         
------------
 100        
------------

== table2 ==================
 id    some_id_1  some_id_2 
----------------------------
 100   NULL       NULL      
----------------------------
 1     100        NULL      
----------------------------
 2     100        NULL      
----------------------------

== table3 ==
 id         
------------
 50         
------------
```

Why these two queries return different values with the line marked with [*]?:

**A)** Without `GROUP BY`

```
SELECT COUNT(table1.id) AS cnt1, COUNT(table2.id) AS cnt2,
    (SELECT COUNT(table2_copy.id) FROM table2 table2_copy
        WHERE table2_copy.some_id_1 = table2.id
    ) AS cnt3,
    (SELECT COUNT(table2_copy.id) FROM table2 table2_copy
        LEFT JOIN table3 ON table2_copy.some_id_2 = table3.id /*[*]*/
        WHERE table2_copy.some_id_1 = table2.id
    ) AS cnt4
FROM table1
INNER JOIN table2 ON (table1.id = table2.id)
WHERE table1.id = 100
```

returns:

```
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  array(4) {
    ["cnt1"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["cnt2"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["cnt3"]=>
    string(1) "2"
    ["cnt4"]=>
    string(1) "2" // Differs from cnt3 query only because of the [*] line
  }
}
```

---

**B)** With `GROUP BY`

```
SELECT COUNT(table1.id) AS cnt1, COUNT(table2.id) AS cnt2,
    (SELECT COUNT(table2_copy.id) FROM table2 table2_copy
        WHERE table2_copy.some_id_1 = table2.id
    ) AS cnt3,
    (SELECT COUNT(table2_copy.id) FROM table2 table2_copy
        LEFT JOIN table3 ON table2_copy.some_id_2 = table3.id /*[*]*/
        WHERE table2_copy.some_id_1 = table2.id
    ) AS cnt4
FROM table1
INNER JOIN table2 ON (table1.id = table2.id)
WHERE table1.id = 100 GROUP BY table1.id /* <-- THE ONLY DIFFERENCE */
```

returns:

```
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  array(4) {
    ["cnt1"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["cnt2"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["cnt3"]=>
    string(1) "2"
    ["cnt4"]=>
    string(1) "0" // <-- DIFFERENT
  }
}
```

**Clarification:** If I change the [*] line by this one (`table3.id` to `table2.id`):

```
LEFT JOIN table3 ON table2_copy.some_id_2 = table2.id
```

It works as I expect: `cnt4` is `2`.

---

**Morever**, these queries (with no table2):

```
SELECT COUNT(table2.id) AS cnt1,
    (SELECT COUNT(table2_copy.id) FROM table2 table2_copy
        WHERE table2_copy.some_id_1 = table2.id
    ) AS cnt3,
    (SELECT COUNT(table2_copy.id) FROM table2 table2_copy
        LEFT JOIN table3 ON table2_copy.some_id_2 = table3.id
        WHERE table2_copy.some_id_1 = table2.id
    ) AS cnt4
FROM table2
WHERE table2.id = 100
```

and:

```
SELECT COUNT(table2.id) AS cnt1,
    (SELECT COUNT(table2_copy.id) FROM table2 table2_copy
        WHERE table2_copy.some_id_1 = table2.id
    ) AS cnt3,
    (SELECT COUNT(table2_copy.id) FROM table2 table2_copy
        LEFT JOIN table3 ON table2_copy.some_id_2 = table3.id
        WHERE table2_copy.some_id_1 = table2.id
    ) AS cnt4
FROM table2
WHERE table2.id = 100 GROUP BY table2.id
```

return both:

```
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  array(3) {
    ["cnt1"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["cnt3"]=>
    string(1) "2"
    ["cnt4"]=>
    string(1) "2"
  }
}
```

So the problem seems to be a combination of these three lines:

```
SELECT (SELECT ...
    LEFT JOIN ... /* THIS LINE */
...) FROM ...
INNER JOIN ... /* THIS LINE */
WHERE ...
GROUP BY ... /* AND THIS LINE */
```

Thanks.

Comment: I'd need more information to be certain, but I'm sure it's because your group by does not include all selected columns. Mysql just chooses the rows when multiple are available in this case.

Comment: Thanks Sebas. Yes, but what if there is only one row to choose? This is the case (check it in the `WHERE` condition), so that's why I don't understand what's happening. By the way, I don't know when you started to read the question, but the data is uploaded at the beginning.

Comment: I'm curious about one thing. Please add `AND table2.id = 100` in your WHERE clause `WHERE table1.id = 100 AND table2.id = 100` and let me know if there's any change

Comment: @Sebas There is no change: cnt4 remains 0 :/

Comment: Something that I don't understand is that, if I create all from the beginning (in a new database) it works good: cnt4 is always 2, but in the database I have it isn't...

Answer (score 0):

*Note: only applies to `MySQL`*

`GROUP BY` is [guaranteed](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html) to return results in order, `DISTINCT` is not.

`GROUP BY` along with `ORDER BY NULL` is of same efficiency as `DISTINCT` (and implemented in the say way). If there is an index on the field being aggregated (or distinctified), both clauses use loose index scan over this field.

In `GROUP BY`, you can return non-grouped and non-aggregated expressions. `MySQL` will pick any random values from from the corresponding group to calculate the expression.

With `GROUP BY`, you can omit the `GROUP BY` expressions from the `SELECT` clause. With `DISTINCT`, you can't. Every row returned by a `DISTINCT` is guaranteed to be unique.

Comment: How do you apply that information to answer this question?

Comment: Group by with Aggregate and without Aggregate work in different way. As I don't have any table data i can't give exact information about why you get 2 in third row when you use group by.

Comment: Okay, I'll try to add the data to the question